# Apply a list of functions to a data frame

Tags: r, purrr, rlang

I have this data frame

```
 test <- data.frame(  a = c(1, "two", "na", 4),
                      b = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                      c = c(1, "nA", 3, 4),
                      d = c("na", NA, TRUE, "5*"),
                      e = c(3, 4, 0.02, 1.5))
```

I created a list of functions using

```
add.filters <- function(...){
  rlang::enquos(...)
}

f <-add.filters(replace(test, test ==3 , 300), replace(test, test ==4 , 400))


f
<list_of<quosure>>

[[1]]
<quosure>
expr: ^replace(test, test == 3, 300)
env:  global

[[2]]
<quosure>
expr: ^replace(test, test == 4, 400)
env:  global
```

Now  I want to apply this list of functions to my data frame so that I get a single date frame with all the functions applied.

I used this function to do that

```
apply.filters <- function(df, list.filtre) {
       purrr::reduce(list.filtre, function(df, filt) {
             rlang::eval_tidy(filt, data = df)
         }, .init = df)
}



apply.filters(test,f)
    a   b   c    d      e
1   1   1   1   na   3.00
2 two   2  nA <NA> 400.00
3  na   3   3 TRUE   0.02
4 400 400 400   5*   1.50
```

But this did not work well, because it applied only the last filter and not the first one (4 changed in 400, but 3 did not change in 300).

What should i do so that the function applies all the filters in the list in order and returns a single data frame with all the filters applied?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the following is happening:

You capture the expression `replace(test, test == 3, 300)` and want to evaluate it in the `data.frame` called `test` which is turned into an environment (this transformation happens in `eval_tidy()`). In this environment, there is no object `test` which is why `test` is looked up in the enclosing environments. There it can be found in the global environment. The output of the first iteration of `reduce` is passed to the second iteration, but, again, the `data.frame` object which is turned into an environment still doesn't contain an object named `test`. Again, `test` will be looked up in the enclosing environments and it will be found **untouched** in the global environment, leading to the output with only `4` changed to `400`.

There are a couple of ways to handle this problem.

#### 1. Make the original approach work

First, lets take some complexity out of the example and just use `add.filters()` and `reduce()` without an enclosing function (we don't need it for the problem at hand).

Also, let's change `rlang::enquos()` which captures an expression and its environment to `rlang::enexprs()` which only captures expressions. Later we will switch back and see why `rlang::enquos()` doesn't work in some constellations.

Let's write a helper function `eval_df()` which we use inside `reduce` instead of the anonymous function. We can also use `debug()` on it to get a better understanding of what's happening.

One approach is to rename the function argument of `eval_df()` to `test` (instead of `df`). Now, when `replace(test ...)` is looking for an object called `test` it will find the `data.frame` that we supplied to the function call. There is no need to search further up the enclosing environments and this time, the result will be as expected:

```r
test <- data.frame(  a = c(1, "two", "na", 4),
                     b = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                     c = c(1, "nA", 3, 4),
                     d = c("na", NA, TRUE, "5*"),
                     e = c(3, 4, 0.02, 1.5))

library(tidyverse)

add.filters <- function(...){
  rlang::enexprs(...)
}

f <- add.filters(replace(test, test ==3 , 300), replace(test, test ==4 , 400))

eval_df <- function(test, e) {
  rlang::eval_tidy(e, data = test)
}

reduce(f, eval_df, .init = test)
#>     a   b   c    d      e
#> 1   1   1   1   na 300.00
#> 2 two   2  nA <NA> 400.00
#> 3  na 300 300 TRUE   0.02
#> 4 400 400 400   5*   1.50
```

This is only possible because we use `rlang::enexprs()` and not `rlang::enquos()`, since the later captures the environment of the expression (the global environment in our case) and again, the evaluation of `replace(test, ...)` would look for the object called `test` in the global environment (where `test` is always unchanged).

```r
add.filters <- function(...){
  rlang::enquos(...)
}

reduce(f, eval_df, .init = test)
#>     a   b   c    d      e
#> 1   1   1   1   na   3.00
#> 2 two   2  nA <NA> 400.00
#> 3  na   3   3 TRUE   0.02
#> 4 400 400 400   5*   1.50
```

#### 2a. A (probably too) easy approach

We could also think of easier ways to achieve the same outcome. For example, loop with `reduce()` over a numeric vector `c(3:4)` and use this within `replace()`:

```r
reduce(c(3:4), function(df, val) {
  replace(df, df == val, val * 100)
}, .init = test)
#>     a   b   c    d      e
#> 1   1   1   1   na 300.00
#> 2 two   2  nA <NA> 400.00
#> 3  na 300 300 TRUE   0.02
#> 4 400 400 400   5*   1.50
```

Of course that will only work in the simple example above, and not with different functions and values.

#### 2b. A somewhat more customizable approach using a lookup table

We could extend this approach and use `reduce2()` on a lookup `data.frame` containing (old) values and new replacements using a custom function `replace_df()`:

```r
replace_df <- function(df, value, replace) {
  replace(df, df == value, replace)
}

lookup_df <- data.frame(val = c(3, 4),
                         repl = c(300, 400)
                         )

reduce2(lookup_df$val,
        lookup_df$repl,
        replace_df,
        .init = test)

#>     a   b   c    d      e
#> 1   1   1   1   na 300.00
#> 2 two   2  nA <NA> 400.00
#> 3  na 300 300 TRUE   0.02
#> 4 400 400 400   5*   1.50
```

#### 3. An approach using a list of functions

I personally would favor a different approach. Instead of capturing the expressions or values, I'd use a list of functions and `reduce` over that list. This approach is more flexible and would support all kind of functions:

```r
f <- list(\(x) replace(x, x == 3 , 300),
          \(x) replace(x, x == 4 , 400))

apply_fn <- function(df, f) {
  f(df)
}

reduce(f, apply_fn, .init = test)
#>     a   b   c    d      e
#> 1   1   1   1   na 300.00
#> 2 two   2  nA <NA> 400.00
#> 3  na 300 300 TRUE   0.02
#> 4 400 400 400   5*   1.50
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: solution #3 is very handsome