# How to apply a list of expressions to a data frame using purrr::reduce()?

Tags: r, rlang

I saw this idea on another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75638113/apply-a-list-of-functions-to-a-data-frame).

I created a list of functions using `rlang::enexprs()`. I want to apply this list on a data frame, so that I get a single frame with all the functions applied.

I have tried something like:

```r
select.expr <- function(...) rlang::enexprs(...)

apply.expr <- function(df, filtre.list) { 
    eval_df <- function(df, expr) rlang::eval_tidy(expr, data = df)
    purrr::reduce(filtre.list, eval_df, .init = df) 
}
```

But it doesn’t work as I would like.  For example:

```r
data <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
                   b = c(2, 2, 2, 2),
                   c = c(3, 3, 3, 3))

expr <- select.expr(replace(data, data == 2, "two"), 
                    replace(data, data == 3, "three"))

apply.expr(data, expr)
##   a b     c
## 1 1 2 three
## 2 1 2 three
## 3 1 2 three
## 4 1 2 three
```

This only works if I pass my data frame `data` as an argument to `eval_df`:

```r
apply.expr <- function(df, filtre.list) { 
    eval_df <- function(data, expr) rlang::eval_tidy(expr, data = data)
    purrr::reduce(filtre.list, eval_df, .init = df) 
}

apply.expr(data, expr)
##   a   b     c
## 1 1 two three
## 2 1 two three
## 3 1 two three
## 4 1 two three
```

But then I cannot use my function `apply.expr()` with another data frame.  I have also tried with `map()`.  Is there a way to create a function that applies a list of expressions to any date frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your `expr` alters `data` and in `apply.expr()` you are changing `df`. Therefore, we should change ```expr`` into:

```
expr <- select.expr(replace(df, df== 2, "two"), 
                    replace(df, df== 3, "three"))
```

which works as expected:

```
apply.expr(data, expr)
  a   b     c
1 1 two three
2 1 two three
3 1 two three
4 1 two three
```

and it works on another dataset:

```
data_alt <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
                   b = c(2, 2, 2, 2),
                   c = c(3, 3, 3, 3))

apply.expr(data_alt, expr)
  a   b     c
1 1 two three
2 1 two three
3 1 two three
4 1 two three
```